# ASP.NET MVC: Downloading an excel file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, excel

I'm downloading an excel file within C# action method the reutrns a FileResult, like this:

```
return File(bindata, "application/octet-stream", "mytestfile.xls");
```

When I manually navigate to the URL that corresponds with the above method, then I get the rendered out representation of the file. The file will not download with a Save As -dialog.

Is there a way to force the download to happen through Save As -dialog?

-pom-

Comment: Are you seeing this happen in a specific browser? And why aren't you using the MIME type for excel files?

Comment: Hi Charles, you're right, this happens only with Opera. Now I tested with FF and Safari, there I get a save dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling you are getting this behavior because of the media type you are returning.

Try changing the media type to application/vnd.ms-excel like this:

```
return File(bindata, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "mytestfile.xls");
```

Comment: you can also use this if is an excel 2010 (xslx): application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Answer (score 8):

Normally when you specify a filename to the `File` method it automatically appends a `Content-Disposition` header so that the Save-As dialog always shows. So I am a bit surprised when you say that your code doesn't work. You could also try to manually set this header:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mytestfile.xls");
```

Comment: Typo is in there, it must be "Content-Disposition"

Comment: @Jared Peless, yes, I have just noticed and fixed that.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this:

```
return new FileContentResult(bindata, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "mytestfile.xls")
            };
```

Hope this helps.