# Downloading excel file in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, download, filecontentresult, fileresult

What I'm trying to implement is giving the users the ability to export the grid data to an excel file and download it, with the help of a file save dialog.

Here's how I have coded it right now -

#### In Javascript -

```
$.post("/irn/Identifier/Download", { "columnValues": columnValues });
```

#### In the Identifier controllers Download action -

```
public FileResult Download(string columnValues)
{
    DTData headlineRows = (DTData)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(columnValues, typeof(DTData));
    var e = new Services.DownloadToExcel();
    return File(e.WriteData(headlineRows), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "testfile.xlsx");
}
```

#### In the DownloadToExcel class, inside the WriteData function I have -

```
//Here, I'm using the EPPlus library to write the column data to an excel file and then i'm returning the data as a byte array -

//Some code that writes the data
return packages.GetAsByteArray();
```

When I run this code, I expect to see a File Save Dialog in the browser, but nothing happens. There aren't any errors on the C# or JavaScript side. Can anyone tell me what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you slap in a Debug.Print("Test") statement in the first line of your `Download` action to ensure that the action is being called at all?  The Debug output will print in the Output panel in Visual Studio.

Comment: I've added breakpoints at every place, and each of these functions are definitely being hit. @user1477388

Comment: Perhaps try changing your application type to the one recommended here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390749/asp-net-mvc-downloading-an-excel-file.

Comment: I've tried that too, doesn't work. The type "application/vdn.ms-excel" is for .xls files, and the one that I'm using is for .xlsx files. I'm starting to think that the code itself is correct, and the issue is something else altogether. @user1477388

Comment: You can try creating an MVC view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301986/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc but the easiest way to do this seems to be to use a grid http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/export-to-excel-or-csv-from-asp-net-mvc-with-c/.  I am not sure why else your code may not be working, but I would recommend one of these other methods.

Comment: Do you think the code as it is written right now seems correct? I'm thinking the reason this doesnt work may be something else entiery. @user1477388

Comment: Honestly, I've not seen that method used anywhere, so I'm not sure.  I can just recommend the methods I know which seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this but forgot to update here -

This worked -

#### Inside my class -

```
private const string MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

private ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();

private FileContentResult excelFile;

Write data using EPPlus

 ...

 ...

 ...

excelFile = File(package.GetAsByteArray(), MimeType, FileName);

 return excelFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

bit late but I was having a similar issue. To solve it I used JSON.stringify(columnValues) on the client to convert my data into a json string before sending it to the controller.

Then instead of using

```
$.post("/irn/Identifier/Download", { "columnValues": columnValues });
```

try

```
var columnValuesString = JSON.stringify(columnvalues);
window.location = '/irn/Identifier/Download?columnvalues=" + columnValuesString';
```

Changing the $.post() to a window.location makes it work.

Then you can deserialize the json string in the controller and your Open/Save dialog should appear after hitting your link.

I hope this helps someone else. Let me know and I can post my code if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I could receive the data properly, but the download pop-up just wouldn't show up. I solved it using MVC's File action. I didn't get a chance to try your solution as I had this working a long time back.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing the site in Internet Explorer, try the following:

- Open Internet Options -> Advanced.  Click Reset.  You can also choose to Restore Advanced Settings.
- Open Internet Options -> Security.  If zones have been changed at all, click "Reset all zones to default level".

Changes to these settings may affect whether or not Internet Explorer accepts file downloads.

More information here:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie-8-will-not-let-me-download-any-files-music-pdf/bc59ba24-866b-4dbf-93f2-85ebb9912c2c

Answer (score 0):

You should use IFrame to help downlaoding the file.

```
function postToIframe( url,data) {
    var target = "downloadIFrame";
    $('<iframe  name="' + target + '" style="display:none"/>').appendTo('body');
    $('body').append('<form action="' + url + '" method="post" target="' + target + '" id="postToIframe"></form>');
    $.each(data, function (n, v) {
        $('#postToIframe').append('<textarea name="' + n + '">' + v + '</textarea>');
    });
    $('#postToIframe').submit().remove();
}
```